# TSQL - get last second of current hour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I need to use a query to get the last second of an hour based on a field in a table.

I have worked this query, which appears to work (SQL Server 2008)

```
SELECT DATEADD(S, -1, DATEADD(hh, 1, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,GETDATE()) / 60 * 60, 0)))
```

Is this the best way to go about this or are there cleaner (more readable) and faster ways. I am considering speed as this will run on a table with a lot of string processing and am trying to optimize where I can.

EDIT: I originally posted the text and subject of this question to read 'last minute of current hour' This was intended to read 'last second'. My mind has obviously shut down for the day. Apologies for my mistake

Comment: Why do you need this?  It looks like you're about to use it for something like `searchDate BETWEEN startPoint AND endPoint`.  If that's the case, seriously consider refactoring your logic to `searchDate >= startPoint AND searchDate < endPoint`.  Then you don't need to find the last minute, or the last second, or the last millisecond, etc, etc.

Comment: @Dems - It is output for a report based on the requirement. Not to be used in a where clause

Comment: Thank you to everyone for swift responses, as always, I am very grateful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query will give you the last **second** not **minute**.
Here is another way.

```
select dateadd(second, -1, dateadd(hour, 1+datediff(hour, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

To get the last minute you can use

```
select dateadd(minute, -1, dateadd(hour, 1+datediff(hour, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Comment: Apologies. Complete mind shutdown as I was typing that out. Meant last second. I am updating my question

Comment: Thanks Mikael. This also i a lot more readable than what I had and I think will pass my team's approval, without the magic '59:59' as proposed. Those strings always raise questions from team approval

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
  select convert(char(13),GETDATE(),121)+':59:59.000'
```

## [SQl Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5168)

Comment: String manipulation will always be slower than DATEADD() alternatives.

Comment: @Dems - thanks for the feedback, I am going with Mikael's approach

Answer (score 1):

I actually had almost the same idea as Joe but I was trying to find out which one is faster, so I ran:

```
SELECT DATEADD(S, -1, DATEADD(hh, 1, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,GETDATE()) / 60 * 60, 0)))
GO 1000
```

and then:

```
select SUBSTRING( convert(varchar(20), GETDATE(),20),1,14)+'59:59'
GO 1000
```

first query ran in 44 seconds, second in 42, so there is not much of a difference. Maybe if you try in your query, it can impact but as far as I could see, it would be almos the same

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. +1 for additional effort